# .NET MAUI Library: XamlC error XFC0000: Cannot Resolve Type

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, maui-community-toolkit

When using Visual Studio to build a .NET MAUI library that contains a reference to the [.NET MAUI Community Toolkit's](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit) [`IsEqualConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/converters/is-equal-converter), the following error is displayed in the Visual Studio Output window:

> XamlC error XFC0000: Cannot resolve type "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit:mct:IsEqualConverter".

This issue also occurs when trying to use other .NET MAUI Community Toolkit Converters in a class Library.

#### Steps To Reproduce

1. Open the solution from the repro repository in Visual Studio.
2. Attempt to build the project. If the problem exists, an `XamlC error XFC0000: Cannot resolve type` error will be reported in the VS Output window for each target platform.

#### Link to public reproduction project repository

https://github.com/awalker-dsg/MauiLibTestLib_ConverterIssue

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiLibTestLib_ConverterIssue.Views.IsEqualConverterPage"
             xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             Title="IsEqualConverterPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <x:String x:Key="MAUI">MAUI</x:String>
        <mct:IsEqualConverter x:Key="IsEqualConverter" />        
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <!-- 
        The code in VerticalStackLayout was taken from the MAUI community toolkit sample code here:
        https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/main/samples/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Sample/Pages/Converters/IsEqualConverterPage.xaml
    -->
    <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="10">
        <Label Text="The IsEqualConverter is a converter that allows users to convert any value binding to a bool depending on whether or not it is equal to a different value. The initial binding contains the object that will be compared and the ConverterParameter contains the object to compare it to."/>
        <Entry Margin="0"
                    Text="{Binding InputValue}" 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        <Label Text="Does the entry text equal &quot;MAUI&quot;?"/>
        <Label FontSize="Large" 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="Yes, it does!"
                    TextColor="Green">
            <Label.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                                    Binding="{Binding InputValue, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource MAUI}}"
                                    Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="No, it doesn't" />
                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Label.Triggers>
        </Label>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [linker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/deployment/visual-studio-properties?view=net-maui-7.0#build-1) is removing our library from your project. This happens when the compiler removes "unused" third-party libraries and it happens because the linker isn't intelligent enough to understand that the library is being used in XAML (it only knows how to scan C# code).

[image]

#### Workaround

Update your XAML code to add `x:Name` which will generate a C# property for the Behavior in your code-behind; during compilation, the linker will now see that you are using `CommunityToolkit.Maui` and will no longer remove it:

```xml
<mct:IsEqualConverter x:Key="IsEqualConverter" x:Name="IsEqualConverter"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my main project my calling to CommunityToolkit.Maui in the xaml worked because in my MauiProgram.cs I had .UseMauiCommunityToolkit();

In my secondary project, my calling to CommunityToolkit.Maui didn't worked when I tried to launch the app.

Thanks to Brandon Minnick response, I found a solution, adding x:Name in my object calling CommunityToolkit.Maui wasn't sufficient for me.

I created in the xaml.cs a fake method using CommunityToolkit.Maui and now my app can compile.

Comment: Could you add your fake method as an example?

Comment: public void FakeMethod() { new AnimationBehavior(); } @Uke